# What happens when old photons (1 billion years old) meets up with new photons (born yesterday) going in the same direction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, space-expansion

Here's an example:

[image]

Light from the left source will be 1 billion years old when it meets up with light from the right source.

How fast should the target be moving according to Hubble's Law?

Assumimg it's 1.5 billion light years from the left source and 500 Mly from the right source.

Answer (score 1):

The target's velocity is zero in its own frame of reference. Since your target is presumably an observer, that's the frame they would naturally use. That observer might naturally ask how fast source 1 and source 2 are moving away from her. This is not guaranteed to be a meaningful question to ask, since general relativity only has local frames of reference, not global ones. It is logically and mathematically self-consistent to say that all three objects (source 1, source 2, and the observer) are at rest, while the space between them expands.

Using a particular cosmological model, one can figure out the time-redshift relation for each of these photons, and find their redshifts $z_1$ and $z_2$. There is no unambiguously correct way to convert these to velocities, since, as described above, GR doesn't define relative velocities for objects at cosmological differences. However, if the distance is short compared to cosmological scales, then this becomes more meaningful to talk about. You could then, to a good approximation, plug these $z$ values into the equation for a kinematic Doppler shift and get velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$. The observer would call these the velocities of sources 1 and 2 away from her, in a frame where she's at rest. These will be unequal, with $v_1>v_2$, because velocities of cosmological expansion depend on distance. (That's what the Hubble relation is.)

BTW, your title talks about photon 2 as "born yesterday," which doesn't seem consistent with the body of the question, where you say it's traveled half a billion light years.

Comment: Ha, you're right. But when the old photon is 1 B yo and the new photon is 1 day old, they still meet up, and presumably travel through the same space for 500 My until they reach the target at the same time. Or is that not true?